# Laravel testing actions requiring authentication

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I am trying to write feature tests for my Laravel app, but some actions require being logged in. How can I do it, to prevent error because of not being logged in? I'm using JWTAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make request with header `Authorization`, accurately reproducing what happens in the real world.

I create one trait for my test cases and use in where need authentication:

In trait you generate JWT valid token for user in header Authorization. In the case i use Tymon package for JWTAuth

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use JWTAuth;

trait CallApiTrait {
    /**
     * Simulate call api
     *
     * @param  string $endpoint
     * @param  array  $params
     * @param  string $asUser
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function callApi($endpoint, $method,$params = [], $email = 'user@email',$password='password')
    {
        $headers = [
            'Accept'=>'application/json',
        ];

        if($email&&$password){
            $token = $token = JWTAuth::attempt(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password]);
            $headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' . $token;
        }

        return $this->json(
            $method,
            $endpoint,
            $params,
            $headers
        );
    }
```

And in my test method

```
    class StudentTest extends TestCase {
    use CallApiTrait;
    ...

    public function test_can_request_with_auth(){
        $rs = $this->callApi(route('foo.bar'),'GET');
        $rs->assertStatus(200);
    }
```